# How do I print a dictionary neatly?

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

I'm trying to print a dictionary nicely. I have this

```
fruits = {'apple': 100,
          'banana': 2,
          'mango': 42}
```

I used `print(fruit)`
but it just outputs: `{'apple': 100, 'banana': 2, 'mango': 42}`

Is there a way I can print it like this:

```
apple 100
banana 2
mango 42
```

Comment: do you want to print following insertion order?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple for loop like this

```
for k,v in fruits.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Output

```
apple 100
banana 2
mango 42
```

To print in descending order:

```
for k,v in sorted(fruits.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(k,v)
```

Output:

```
apple 100
mango 42
banana 2
```

Comment: How would I do it if I wanted to print it in descending order? So it prints apples first because it has 100 then mano because it was 42 then banana because it has 2

Comment: You could sort `fruits.items()` like so: `sorted(fruits.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)`

Comment: @user3483203 Could you post it as an answer. I didn't quiet understand

Comment: @user3483203 what is lambda

Comment: @SarahChan SO is a treasurechest full of informations - research instead of asking q after q after q: [how to sort dictionary by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key) and [why are lambdas usefull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful/890188#890188)

Answer (score 3):

This is one approach using `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
fruits = {'apple': 100,
          'banana': 2,
          'mango': 42}

fruits = "\n".join("{0} {1}".format(k, v)  for k,v in fruits.items())
print(fruits)
```

**Output:**

```
mango 42
apple 100
banana 2
```